# FIleMaker + Windows 7: Web Viewer Memory Issues

Tags: memory-management, windows-7, memory-leaks, filemaker

My company has developed a pretty massive FileMaker app. Instead of using FileMaker's Container object to handle pictures, I more or less wrote my own version of 360Works SuperContainer in Rails and I have it running on a server in our office; pictures show up through the Web Viewer.

The app seemed to work fine at first, but then the complaints came rolling in - "My computer's really slow!" "I can't see the pictures!" - and so on and so forth. A quick peek into Task Manager showed that FileMaker was consuming an enormous amount of memory. Apparently, the Web Viewer caches all data in system memory, and only removes stuff from memory if FileMaker switches to a layout that doesn't have a Web Viewer. To remedy this, I wrote a script to switch to a non-Web Viewer layout and back and wired it up to a button. It's a bit ugly, but it was getting the job done.

This was working great for everyone, until a few weeks ago. We finally upgraded all the computers in the office from beat-up Dells running Windows XP to custom-built machines running Windows 7. For some reason, when I run the layout switch script, it only flushes *some* of the memory. Here's a quick breakdown of memory consumption in KB after certain actions:

> Start: 58482
>
> Loaded DB: 71024
>
> Browsed 50 records: 247820
>
> Flushed: 81512
>
> Browsed 50 records: 272848
>
> Flushed: 86264

And hundreds - thousands - of records are browsed, daily. Compounded with the fact that my users never ever want to reboot their systems, I am constantly getting called from my office to do just that.

I know that in Windows, FileMaker's Web Viewer runs on the IE rendering engine... I was wondering if there were any way to set it to clear the memory after each page load or something. Our company pretty much depends on this app to function, and when this app isn't working smoothly, nothing works smoothly - so I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Please report this bug to FileMaker. Let me know if you need contact info at FileMaker.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the

```
Set Web Viewer [Object Name: "wbvName"; Action:Reset]
```

script step?

You may want to drop a script that does that in your `OnRecordChange` script trigger.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave that a shot, but it does nothing to free up any memory.

Answer (score 1):

We've also seen this, and whilst I have not found a 'fix' as such for it, when changing tabs , putting a =< 0.001 pause in seems to help

Comment: Putting a pause in where, exactly? How does it seem to help?

Comment: When we were changing records (and still do up to FM15) you can see the RAM climb, so when it was a scripted next record, we put tiny pauses in.  I investigated this some more the other day, and switching to a layout without the webviewer on, waiting a couple of seconds and the RAM would drop back to normal. On FM16, this was no where near as bad and the RAM would drop back of its own accord on the same layout.